# Which SQL Read TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL do I want for long running insert?

Tags: sql-server-2005, performance, transactions

I have a long running insert transaction that inserts data into several related tables.

When this insert is running, I cannot perform a select * from MainTable.  The select just spins its wheels until the insert is done.

I will be performing several of these inserts at the same/overlapping time.  To check that the information is not inserted twice, I query the MainTable first to see if an entry is there and that its processed bit is not set.

During the insert transaction, it flips the MainTable processed bit for that row.

So I need to be able to read the table and also be able to tell if the specific row is currently being updated.

Any ideas on how to set this up in Microsoft SQL 2005?  I am looking through the [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) documentation.

Thank you,
Keith

**EDIT:**  I do not think that the same insert batch will happen at the same time.  These are binary files that are being processed and their data inserted into the database.  I check that the file has not been processed before I parse and insert the data.  When I do the check, if the file has not been seen before I do a quick insert into the MainTable with the processed bit set false.

Is there a way to lock the row being updated instead of the entire table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to rethink your process before you use READ UNCOMMITTED. There are many good reasons for isolated transactions. If you use READ UNCOMMITTED you may still get duplicates because there is a chance both of the inserts will check for updates at the same time and both not finding them creating duplicates. Try breaking it up into smaller batches or issue periodic COMMITS

EDIT

You can wrap the MainTable update in a transaction that will free up that table quicker but you still may get conflicts with the other tables.

ie

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT @ProcessedBit = ProcessedBit FROM MainTable WHERE ID = XXX

IF  @ProcessedBit = False
    UPDATE MainTable SET ProcessedBit = True WHERE ID = XXX

COMMIT TRANSACTION

IF  @ProcessedBit = False
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    -- start long running process
    ...
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

EDIT to enable error recovery

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT @ProcessedStatus = ProcessedStatus FROM MainTable WHERE ID = XXX

IF  @ProcessedStatus = 'Not Processed'
    UPDATE MainTable SET ProcessedBit = 'Processing' WHERE ID = XXX

COMMIT TRANSACTION

IF  @ProcessedStatus = 'Not Processed'
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    -- start long running process
    ...

   IF No Errors
   BEGIN
       UPDATE MainTable SET ProcessedStatus = 'Processed' WHERE ID = XXX
       COMMIT TRANSACTION
   ELSE
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

END
```

Comment: DJ, The problem I would see with your example is that the ProcessedBit is set true before the long process is ran.  If the long process errors, then I am left with the ProcessedBit = true.  Thank you for you help. Keith

Comment: Yeah you have to have a status field instead - with three values: Not Processed, Processing, and Processed

Answer (score 0):

The only isolation level that allows one transaction to read changes executed by another transaction in progress (before it commits) is:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```